# how to define a grid and snap windows to it?

Tags: window-management, gala

What i want no achieve is something like this,

[image: window split in four]

how do i go about defining grids and snap windows to them?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a feature associated with a [tiling WM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). Gala is a floating WM and does not support anything more advanced than window snapping.

An alternative would be to 'fake' tiling features using something like [Stiler](https://github.com/TheWanderer/stiler), which lets you bind keys to resize / move windows, emulating the behaviour of a tiling WM.

Comment: Does this work well on Loki? The repo hasn't been updated since 2009.
Can you point me to any other scripts or programs like this?

Comment: Stiler uses wmctrl to manage windows, so it shouldn't have any issue running on Loki. Make sure you install wmctrl though as it won't work without it!

Comment: We are talking possibilities of even basic compositing WMs like xfwm4, which has exactly the functionality OP is asking for. Also many other non-tiling WMs have such feature, including Kwin, Unity (compiz?), Cinnamon (muffin, fork of Gnome's mutter), and even Mate with marco WM. Not to mention Win10 now :D It's not unreasonable to want this from Gala :)